# co-opt a default Android phone OS screen and add a button without changing OS files?

Tags: android

I've done desktop programming and (ancient) WinMo programming, but have not yet dipped my toes into Andoid programming (but I do use an Android smartphone). I have an idea for a smartphone project, but don't know if this is possible from a security perspective.

On the default screen that pops up when you tap an 'unknown' phone number in the call list, I'd like to add another option next to the "add to contacts" option that would then open my app's interface. Is this possible? For example, can an app 'float' a button over the default OS screen at the target coordinates?

I understand the app would have to be loaded by the user in advance.

If I get my idea working, I would want to distribute it for free through the app store, without asking users to jailbreak their devices, so I think that means no changes to the default OS screen/files directly.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Not really.

> For example, can an app 'float' a button over the default OS screen at the target coordinates?

That part is possible.

> On the default screen that pops up when you tap an 'unknown' phone number in the call list

The "call list" is from an app. There are any number of apps that implement a "call list". Devices will ship with whatever app they choose to that implements a "call list", probably an app written by the device manufacturer themselves. Only some devices might ship with a stock "call list" that is part of the Android Open Source Project (AOSP).

Plus, apps have versions. They change over time. The look and behavior of any given "call list" will vary, even for devices that use a stock app.

Then, of course, there are third-party apps that offer a "call list".

So, there is no single "default screen", but rather hundreds, perhaps thousands.

In addition:

- You have no good way to detect that this screen is in the foreground
- You have no way at runtime to access the UI of the "default screen" (exception: rooted devices) to somehow dynamically determine where to place your button
- You have no way to read any of the information off of that screen, and so there is no particular point in your having a button on that screen in the first place -- the button could be anywhere and have the same functionality